# jQuery/Ajax..... Scripts conflicting on processResults

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

Ok...  so I have this widget app....

jQuery/Ajax... jsonp... async=true...everything works fine except....

I have two javascript code blocks.... 
the first is appended to the head....

and the second goes in a division of the html body that is loaded by the Ajax script...

the second script contains a function that is loaded by the first.....

getting an fatal error in firebug: Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined....
checked everything inside the function... (the combo works fine outside of ajax)

It appears that the script are not loading correctly, although they both are loaded in the right places....

Tried them both ways... 1 then 2 and 2 then 1.... error both ways...

Pulling what hair I have left out over this....
Any ideas, comments, recommendations, questions welcomed !

UPDATE:  Sorry guys...  I must be going blind....  the second script is not a function... it consists of one js object and two js variables which feed the function which is actually in script one in the head.

Comment: Have you wrapped the function in the head within a `$(document).ready({...});` block?

Comment: No.... but I thought about that... I am thinking that doc.ready won't work since the page is already 'loaded'.... the ajax is updating the content divs...  to wit... the 'original' page source never changes as a result of the ajax scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... in case anybody else finds themselves in the same boat....

Here's how I got this running securely.....

1. I created a blank JS object in the head....

   ```
   var addthis_share = {"title":"", "description":"", "url":"" };
   ```

then....

1. I just updated them dynamically in the content item divs.....
   something like this....

   ```
   addthis_share.title = "...$PHP_title....";      
   addthis_share.description = "...$PHP_description....";
   addthis_share.url = "...$PHP_url....";
   ```

... works for me !